# Drawing route on the map with over 30 coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem in  my project about drawing route on the map. The Question is that I have so many coordinates (about 30) in an arraylist. I have searched so many drawing route topic on the web,but all topics are about drawing route src to dest. My problem is my arraylist items are not sorted . So that when I try to drawing route 0 to 1, 1 to 2 indexes the route is not correct and looking like a maze . I need your help. I have over 30 **non-sorted** items and I want to draw route using all items.

Thanks, Tugrul.

Comment: Well, how do you want points to be connected and what is sorting criteria? It looks like solving [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). Or, in easier case - task of [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) building

Comment: Single and non directed connection. In real, I want to draw a route which shows some of the public transport vehicles (e.g bus ) travelling locations. For example I want to go x city then y city then z city and finaly w city. But I have the list which is sorted like z y x w (Non-sorted mean is that.). So that when I want to draw 0 to 1 , 1 to 2 indexes and so on, it is not like what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Route means it must have a source and destination. Without source and destination how you can draw a route ?

From where you are getting 30 items ? How you know those are non-sorted ?

You have to use a service (e.g., google) to get route or internal service. If you are getting wrong route, your drawing will look like maze only.

Comment: Imagine you have a bunch of pizzas and need to deliver them burning the least amount of fuel possible. That is an example where you don't have a destination but certainly have to build some king of good route.

Comment: Services like Google will help in getting from one point to another, but would not help in which order to visit them

Comment: I have using google service. I mean that I have 30 coordinates. I can draw a route point to point. But I have to use 30 items to draw.

Comment: Single and non directed connection. In real, I want to draw a route which shows some of the public transport vehicles (e.g bus ) travelling locations. For example I want to go x city then y city then z city and finaly w city. But I have the list which is sorted like z y x w (Non-sorted mean is that.). So that when I want to draw 0 to 1 , 1 to 2 indexes and so on, it is not like what I want. This is  my problem.

Comment: From an xml file.  My project is drawing route of some public transport vehicles. I have to visit all stations in my route. I have all coordinates of stations but the list is not sorted. Sorted mean that firsly  visit A station then B station and so on. But I have the list B, A, C  etc. When I try to draw route point to point with consecutive elements,the route is not correct. It draws B to A and A to C, but A to B, B to C is so different.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-tsp-solver/ this project does what you want in Google Maps using Javascript.

I think it would be simple to convert it to Java (or just use HTML5 app)